# Console.log and actual values in Box2D JS structures

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, box2d

Sorry for bad English, I need a little help with understanding what's happening in Box2D Javascript structures.

I've got an instance of collision between 2 bodies:

```
var contact = b2Contact.Create(shape1, shape2, this.m_world.m_blockAllocator);
```

It's complicated Prototype-based struct. When I want to see the coordinates of collisions - like

```
console.log(contact.m_manifold[0].points[0].position)
```

I have pretty output:

> klass
>
> x: 333.09257050755764
>
> y: 295.312523134946
>
> **proto**: Object

But the problem is: actual x and y are undefined. I got it with call

```
console.log(contact.m_manifold[0].points[0].position.x)
```

So what's the cause of such strange behavior and how that useful fields could be used?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the output of the next commands? (assuming you are using Firebug):

`console.dir(contact.m_manifold[0].points[0].position)`

`console.log(typeof contact.m_manifold[0].points[0].position.x)`

`console.log(typeof contact.m_manifold[0].points[0].position.proto.x)`